# Is there a direct proof of the inequality $cyclic \sum\frac {a^2+1}{b+c}\ge 3$

Tags: inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ reals.
Prove that
$$cyclic \sum\frac {a^2+1}{b+c}\ge 3$$

I proved it using Nesbitt inequality
$$cyclic \sum \frac {a}{b+c} \ge \frac {3}{2} $$
and the fact that
$$a+\frac {1}{a}\ge 2$$

But i would like to know if there is a straight proof without Nesbitt inequality.

Comment: Given that Nesbitt's inequality can be proved with a [single application of AM-HM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality#First_proof:_AM-HM), that already looks quite straightforward to me.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but: what is cyclic?

Comment: @RobertSoupe $a $ becomes $b $ becomes $c $ becomes $a $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k=a+b+c$. Then

$$\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}=\frac{a^2-k^2+k^2+1}{k-a}=-a-k+\frac{k^2+1}{k-a}$$

So,

\begin{align*}
cyclic\sum\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}&=-a-b-c-3k+(k^2+1)\left(\frac{1}{k-a}+\frac{1}{k-b}+\frac{1}{k-c}\right)\\
&\ge -4k+3(k^2+1)\left(\frac{3}{(k-a)+(k-b)+(k-c)}\right)
\end{align*}

as $\textrm{A.M.}\ge\textrm{H.M.}$

\begin{align*}
-4k+3(k^2+1)\left(\frac{3}{(k-a)+(k-b)+(k-c)}\right)&=-4k+\frac{9(k^2+1)}{2k}\\
&=\frac{k}{2}+\frac{9}{2k}\\
&\ge3
\end{align*}

as $\textrm{A.M.}\ge\textrm{G.M.}$

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}\geq2\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}}\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c)}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}}=\sqrt{2(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}}\geq\sqrt{(1+1+1)^2}=3.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Using CS and then AM-GM,
$$\sum \frac{a^2}{b+c} +\sum \frac1{b+c}\geqslant \frac{a+b+c}2+\frac9{2(a+b+c)}\geqslant 3$$

Comment: Could you explain how do you use CS.

Comment: $\sum \dfrac{a^2}{b+c}=\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum (b+c)}=\frac12(a+b+c)$ - check https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/ for this particular form of CS.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you Tacavity.